# AUTOINCREMENT not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create a table with 1 predefine row in it.
So, I am adding the row in onCreate();

Following is my code :

```
private static final String CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE CATEGORYTABLE (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, category_name VARCHAR(255));";

private static final String DROP_CATEGORY_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CATEGORYTABLE";

private static final String INSERT_PREDEFINED_CATEGORY = "INSERT INTO CATEGORYTABLE VALUES('Category 1');";

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_CATEGORY_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(INSERT_PREDEFINED_CATEGORY); <-- error on this line 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error Message :

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table CATEGORYTABLE has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied

Failure 1 (table CATEGORYTABLE has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied) on 0x287cb8 when preparing 'INSERT INTO CATEGORYTABLE VALUES('Home');'.
```

Is this the correct way to insert a predefined row in a table?
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table has 2 columns so you will either need to provide 2 values, or specify the column names you want to insert to. Change

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORYTABLE VALUES('Category 1')
```

to

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORYTABLE VALUES(NULL, 'Category 1')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORYTABLE(category_name) VALUES('Category 1')
```

For what it's worth, it's also a bad practice to catch exceptions in `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()`. If there's a problem, the callback should not return normally.